# TogleButton Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmc9O.png)

```
                 Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: Center(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: screenWidth * 0.92,
                color: Constants.colorGrisNuevo,
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                        left: 100.0,
                        child: Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            height: 50,
                            width: screenWidth * 0.80)), //atras
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 50.0,
                        width: screenWidth * 0.60,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

I am trying to recreate this pair of buttons, but the truth is that the animation I will not be able to do, is there a pub dev plugin already? What to solve this ?, Eye all my code is not completed, some details were missing with the containers.

**(Edit)** I managed to replicate the widget, is there a way to make an animation for the color change? Or is this a horizontal gesture with the finger?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int activeIndex = 0;

  final texts = ['Sale ahoro', 'Programar retiro'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final chidren = texts.map(
      (e) {
        final index = texts.indexOf(e);
        return Expanded(
          child: Button(
            text: e,
            onTap: () => setState(() => activeIndex = index),
            isActivated: activeIndex == index,
          ),
        );
      },
    ).toList();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: chidren,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  const Button({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.isActivated,
  });

  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final bool isActivated;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isActivated ? const Color(0xFF5e50ff) : Colors.grey[300],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        ),
        height: 50,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: isActivated ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[600],
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```